# Multplie Series Scatter Plot

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I need to plot multiple series from one table, all of the series on the same graph.. So when I add new data to the table I don't have to reselect all the series for the appropriate graphs. I would like to select the series column and then plot the following:

- d vs. Torque
- d vs Price
- Torque vs Price

Sample Data:

```
SERIES   d(X)   Torque       Cost
RFN      70     120.00       10.00 
KKG      70     110.00       12.00 
PPG      80     150.00       14.00 
SAP      70     110.00       19.00 
RFN      80     115.00       14.00 
RFN      90     130.00       20.00 
PPG      70     125.00       11.00 
SAP      100    145.00       35.00 
KKG      100    160.00       25.00 
SAP      90     135.00       25.00 
SAP      100    170.00       50.00 
PPG      80     130.00       16.00
```

Is there a quicker way(less tables. etc) of doing it than: [Excel scatter plot with multiple series from 1 table](https://superuser.com/questions/750353/excel-scatter-plot-with-multiple-series-from-1-table)

Otherwise I need to create a table for each plot that I want to create?

Thank you

Comment: Unless you want to use VBA to automate things, the solution from charting guru Jon Peltier in your link is the way to go.

Comment: Hi Teylyn, you provide any help with the VBA? To be honest, I am too lazy to do all the tables. I have about 12 series (and growing) and I have more then just the 3 variables mentioned that I need to plot, about 6) If the simplest solution is Jon Peltier's then that is what I will use! Thank you

Comment: As a volunteer who spends precious free after hours and weekend time to  answer questions here without any personal gain, reading "I'm too lazy" does not really tickle my fancy. I'm moving on. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway. I ended up doing the tables. They were a bit of a mess to get going but I soon got the hang of it and was pretty quick. I just prefer not to use VBA if I don't have to. Cheers

Comment: @teylyn When the OP says, "lazy," he simply means that he's looking for a practical solution.  I decided over a decade ago that if something requires VB, I need to switch to Python or simplify my approach in Excel.