# How to have a color-specified scatter plot in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a table of information in excel in which I have a column for some attribute and two columns of for example X and Y information. I want to plot them in scatter form but with specified color for each attribute. I want to know how to do this in excel. My table is something like the following:

[image]

I want to have for all points with label "A", color A, for all points with label "B", color B and for label "C", color C for example.

How can I do this automatically? My data set and number of labels are so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel scatter plot with multiple series from 1 table](https://superuser.com/questions/750353/excel-scatter-plot-with-multiple-series-from-1-table)

Answer (score 2):

First, create a scatter plot on just one of the attributes (A, for example).

Then, copy the X and Y data (not the labels) for the next attribute, select the chart object, then use Home>Paste>Paste Special from the ribbon to paste the copied data as a **new series**.

[image]

Be sure to select the chart before using Paste Special.

Repeat this process until you have a chart with as many series as attributes. Then edit the series name to whatever you choose.

Comment: How can I do this automatically? I have a large amount of data and Labels!

Answer (score 2):

Apart Paste Special, we could also use Select Date Source.

Go to Insert > Choose one Scatter Graphic in Charts group, then we will get a blank chart.

Right click this blank chart > Select Date Source > click Add > Enter the Series Name, such as Label A, select the data range for X values and Y values.

[image]

Do the same step but select different date ranges for other Label B and Label C.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this automatically? I have a lot of Label!